# VBA doesn't include every sheet in pdf output

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm attempting to output 4 sheets into one pdf file, but for some reason the output only includes the first sheet, "Report 1a". Here's my code:

```
Dim Ref As Worksheet

Set Ref = Worksheets("Charts for Report")

Sheets(Array("Report 1a", "Report 1b", "Report 2", "Comments")).Select
Sheets("Report 1a").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "T:\QA\Sample Reports\Reports for CCC\" & Ref.[B1] _
    & " - " & Ref.[B2] & " - " & Worksheets("Provider Data").[I2] & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Worksheets("Report 1a").Select
```

I've even tried recording a macro to see what I'm doing wrong. It'll work (i.e., include all 4 pages) when I record it, but if I try to rerun it it'll only put include the first page ("Report 1a").

Comment: `Sheets("Report 1a").Activate` get rid of this line.

Comment: @Masoud I swear I've tried that before, but for some reason that change works now. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Every line of code works as written. ;)

Comment: @Masoud I take that back, it stopped working again. :( This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot look further into it at the time but this post may help you; https://danwagner.co/how-do-i-save-multiple-sheets-as-a-single-pdf/ fingers crossed.

Comment: The only thing that seems to work (so far) is hiding every sheet except the ones I want to export, and then exporting the entire workbook. If this continues to work I'll write it up as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what was going wrong, but I at least found a solution.

Prior to exporting anything I hid all the worksheets that I didn't want included. (All the more reason to avoid select like the plague!)

```
Sub Hide_non_Packet_Sheets()
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim SheetExists As Worksheet

    For index = 1 To 50
        Set SheetExists = Sheets(index)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Sheets(index).Name = "Page1" Or Sheets(index).Name = "Page2" Then
            Sheets(index).Visible = True
            Else
            Sheets(index).Visible = False
            End If
        Next index
End Sub
```

Then I just export the entire workbook:

```
ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= "C:\Place\Name.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas :=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

And then you can set a macro to unhide sheets when you're done exporting if you want.